# Inheriting a django form with validation

Tags: django

I have one form that must be inherited by a second one. The field as well as **validation** behavior (my Google-fu fails me on this) of the parent must be active in the child.

This is an example of a form with fields and validation behavior I want to be inherited:

```
class INeedForm(forms.Form):
    i_need = forms.ChoiceField(
        label = "I need",
        choices= [
        ("select", "Select"),
        ("only", "The only choice"),
        ],
        initial = "select",
        widget = forms.Select(attrs = {'class' : 'form-control'}))

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(INeedForm, self).clean()

        i_need = cleaned_data.get("i_need")
        if i_need == "select":
            self.add_error('i_need', "Please select one")
```

Comment: OK. So, what is not working when you try this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end of method `clean` you should return `cleaned_data`.

And you can inherit your `INeedForm` and it's behaviour:

```
class NewForm(INeedForm):
    # If you need inherit Meta
    class Meta(INeedForm.Meta):
        pass
```